# Website (file system & database) backups never seem to complete

Tags: azure, backup, azure-storage

I'm trying to get my website (file system & database) to backup in Azure portal but the backup does not seem to ever complete. The steps i have taken are as follows:

- I went to my website
- Clicked on backups
- I chose my storage account and also added a database backup too.
- I hit save
- I wanted to test that the backup was working so i clicked "backup". It stated that "Successfully started backup for web app '...'.

I have left it for an hour and i cannot see any backups in my storage account.

The site is quite small and so is the database.

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

**Side note:** The same kind of thing happens in the new preview portal too... It just doesn't seem to finish the backup process.

I followed this tutorial: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3057/windows-azure-sql-database-backup-and-restore-strategy/

---

**SIDE NOTE:** I removed the database backup and this allowed the process to complete... I wonder if there is a bug in the backup process?

Comment: Anything i can add to improve the question (re the down vote)?

Comment: Are you trying to backup your website (as the topic title says) or do you want to backup a database (like describes in the link that you supplied)?

Comment: The Azure backup encapsulates a file system backup wit a database. I've changed the title and content of my OP a little but i did state: "I chose my storage account and also added a database backup too."

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the credentials you are using for the database in your Connection Strings in the portal do not have sufficient rights to script out the database. The backup routine needs to script out your DB and extract all your data to work properly.

Here is a helpful article on how to create a backup on Azure WebApps and Database.  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-backup/